# ubuntu /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s

Tags: compiling, shared-library, fortran

I am compiling a fortran program by using `g77` on Ubuntu 14.04, I got the following error:

```
ubuntu /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
```

Didn't you ever have experience with such problem?

Comment: My ubuntu is 14.04 version

Comment: Could you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/460369/edit) it and add more info on what you are trying to do or to compile? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a library. This command should install the necessary dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1-dev
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5850955/1505348

Comment: That command installs libz and has absolutely nothing to do with the missing libgcc_s.a, which is almost certainly caused by static linking, not the absence of any variant of libgcc_s.